# Getting corrupted Excel file with JasperReports on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, opensuse

I used this codes to export report as *Excel* file with *JasperReports 4.6*:

```
  File reportFile = new File(externalContextAuthenticationConfiguration.getReportTempFolderUrl());
    File outputFile = File.createTempFile("reportOutput", ".XLS", reportFile);
    JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, outputFile);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);

    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    exporterXLS.exportReport();
    return outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

This code is working well in Windows but when the project goes to OpenSuse Linux the created Excel file is like this picture :

[image]

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you check resulted file with *MS Office*?

Comment: yes , when I open it with MS Office it is corrupted too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem :
The problem was not in JasperReport.
It creates the report in Excel extension correctly but when the app server sends it to client the problem happens

We used this code for sending the report to client :

```
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Cp1256");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel-download");
```

but application/vnd.ms-excel-download is just for Windows Excel and it destroys the Excel file report in Linux.

Now, I am using this code to zip it instead and then send it to the client so it works both on Windows and Linux server :

```
        File zipFile = new File(fileName.replace("XLS", "ZIP"));
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        addFileToZip("", fileName, zipOutputStream, false);
        zipOutputStream.flush();
        zipOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about this logic. You download file as zip and then locally you rename it (manually) to xlsx ? I am getting same issue and I noticed, that xlsx downloaded files can not be unzipped normally when you change extension to zip. ...